# Strange initialization behavior for an array constructor with implied do in gfortran

Tags: arrays, constructor, fortran, intel, gfortran

Let's say I have 3 double-precision arrays,

```
real*8, dimension(n) :: x, y, z
```

which are initialized as

```
x = 1.
y = (/ (1., i=1,n) /)
z = (/ (1. +0*i, i=1,n) /)
```

They should initialize all elements of all arrays to `1`. In `ifort` (16.0.0 20150815), this works as intended for any `n` within the range of the declared precision. That is, if we initialize `n` as

```
integer*4, parameter :: n
```

then as long as `n < 2147483647`, the initialization works as intended for all declarations.

In `gfortran` (4.8.5 20150623 Red Hat 4.8.5-16), the initialization fails for `y` (array comprehension with constant argument) as long as `n>65535`, **independent** of its precision. AFAIK, `65535` is the maximum of a `unsigned short int`, aka `unsigned int*2` which is well within the range of `integer*4`.

Below is an MWE:

```
program test
    implicit none

    integer*4, parameter :: n = 65536
    integer*4, parameter :: m = 65535
    real*8, dimension(n) :: x, y, z
    real*8, dimension(m) :: a, b, c
    integer*4 :: i

    print *, huge(n)

    x = 1.
    y = (/ (1., i=1,n) /)
    z = (/ (1.+0*i, i=1,n) /)
    print *, x(n), y(n), z(n)

    a = 1.
    b = (/ (1., i=1,m) /)
    c = (/ (1.+0*i, i=1,m) /)
    print *, a(m), c(m), c(m)
end program test
```

Compiling with `gfortran` (`gfortran test.f90 -o gfortran_test`), it outputs:

```
  2147483647
   1.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000     
   1.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000
```

Compiling with `ifort` (`ifort test.f90 -o ifort_test`), it outputs:

```
2147483647
   1.00000000000000        1.00000000000000        1.00000000000000     
   1.00000000000000        1.00000000000000        1.00000000000000
```

What gives?

Comment: Have you tried with a newer gfortran? Looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: Same behavior using the latest one I have available: GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: Still looks like a compiler bug. Report it.

Comment: Also might be good to see the GIMPLE form of the code, whether the compiler really uses a 16-bit integer (I would find that surprising).

Comment: Worth noting that for default `real` the error goes away. I agree it is better to use a standard declaration and not the `*4` and `*8`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am a very novice Fortran programmer, so I am not entirely sure how to generate the GIMPLE form of the code, nor what "standard Fortran" is. Could anyone point me towards any resources?

@VladimirF, I actually encountered this when using `c_iso_binding` with all my integers being `c_int` and all my reals being `c_double`. I thought `*4` or `*8` was more common, so I switched to that. Interesting to discover that using just `real` works. `real(kind=8)` or `real(kind=4)` fails as well.

Comment: Does really `real(kind=4)` fail as well? It shouldn't if just `real` doesn't! And indeed, it does not fail for me. `kind=4` and `kind=8` is what compiler uses inside, but use something more portable for your programs.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! It does *not* fail. I failed to recompile after changing to `kind=8`, my bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed a big difference in how the compiler treats the array constructors. For `n<=65535` there is the actual array of [1., 1., 1.,...] stored in the object file (or in some of the intermediate representations).

For a larger array the compiler generates a loop:

```
    (*(real(kind=8)[65536] * restrict) atmp.0.data)[offset.1] = 1.0e+0;
    offset.1 = offset.1 + 1;
    {
      integer(kind=8) S.2;

      S.2 = 0;
      while (1)
        {
          if (S.2 > 65535) goto L.1;
          y[S.2] = (*(real(kind=8)[65536] * restrict) atmp.0.data)[S.2];
          S.2 = S.2 + 1;
        }
      L.1:;
    }
```

it appears to me, that first it sets only one element of a temporary array and then it copies the (mostly undefined) temporary array to `y`. And that is wrong. Valgrind also reports usage of uninitialized memory.

For a default real we have

```
    while (1)
      {
        if (shadow_loopvar.2 > 65536) goto L.1;
        (*(real(kind=4)[65536] * restrict) atmp.0.data)[offset.1] = 1.0e+0;
        offset.1 = offset.1 + 1;
        shadow_loopvar.2 = shadow_loopvar.2 + 1;
      }
    L.1:;
    {
      integer(kind=8) S.3;

      S.3 = 0;
      while (1)
        {
          if (S.3 > 65535) goto L.2;
          y[S.3] = (*(real(kind=4)[65536] * restrict) atmp.0.data)[S.3];
          S.3 = S.3 + 1;
        }
      L.2:;
    }
```

We have two loops now, one sets the *whole* temporary array and the second one copies that to `y` and everything is fine.

### Conclusion: a compiler bug.

The issue was fixed by GCC developers who read this question. The bug is tracked at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84931

They also identified that the problem is connected to type conversion. The constructor has default precision `1.` and with single precision array there is no type conversion, but for a double precision array there is some type conversion. That caused the difference for these two cases.

Comment: "it sets only one element of a temporary array and then it copies the (mostly undefined) temporary array to `y`"

Inspecting the array visually, this is what seems to be happening. The first element is fine, all others are either `0` of very large numbers, aka, mostly undefined. I'll report it then!